# Javascript: object1 = object2 produce what exactly?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have 2 type of objects:

```
object1 : {
    value : { foo1: {}, foo2: 5 }, state: true, etc = {}
}
```

And

```
object2 : {
    value : { foo1: { value: 5}, foo2: 6 }, state: true, etc = {}
}
```

If I do `object1=object2` what exactly happens with object1 on all levels please.

Comment: A reference to *object2* is assigned to *object1*. What do you expect? If you were to compare the objects using `==` or `===` the result will be *false*. There are no levels, the behaviour is clearly explained in the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: What happens with inner objects? That is the question..

Comment: you broke the reference to the old object ... so it is gone at least as far as `object1` is concerned

Comment: @thednp—nothing. The only thing that changed is the value of *object1* so that it now references a different object. The thing that it previously referenced still exists until nothing references it, then it's available for garbage collection (which may happen at some time determined by the host environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to simplify that a bit:

```
var a = { value: 1, aStuff: true };
var b = { value: 2, bStuff: true };
b = a;
console.log(b); // { value: 1, aStuff: true }
```

Now `a` and `b` reference the same object. Think of it like the same object is accessible by two names. Which means this happens when you change that object:

```
a.value = 5
console.log(a); // { value: 5, aStuff: true }
```

Two names, one object.

So what happened to what to the `{ value: 2, bStuff: true }` object? Once you tell `b` to reference a different object then no existing variable has a reference to it, so eventually the garbage collector will find it and dispose of it.

---

> What happens with inner objects? That is the question..

Nothing at all. The outer object still holds references the values it contains. All that's changed is that you have two variables pointing to that same outer object.

Answer (score 2):

`object1` is now a reference of `object2`, any change in `object1`, will change `object2`;

```
var object1 = { foo: 'bar' };

var object2 = {
    value : { foo1: { value: 5}, foo2: 6 }
};

object1 = object2; // the { foo: 'bar' } is gone.

object1.foo2 = 7; //This changes object2.foo2 value
console.log(object2.foo2); //7
```